# how to text align center for the text with space and line break

Tags: javascript, html, css, center, text-align

I have the following example below:

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 43px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="wrapper" autosize>THE GREAT BANGKOK SALE</textarea>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ngoctuan001/cgLvh62o/2/

As you can see, I want to text-align the text in the `textarea` tag. Because the text area got a fixed width, it will try to break to next line when there is a space. However, when that happen, that row is slightly not center in human eyes due to the space.

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the screen shot above, the red line in the right hand side is always slightly longer than the red line in the left hand side, this is because the computer treats the space (highlighted) as 1 more character. But in human eyes, this is not considered as center aligned

Is there anyway to fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: Try to use `flex` with `align-items: center;`

Comment: @Awais you mean add   "display: flex;align-items: center;" to the textarea ? i tried but it didnt change anything

Comment: Yes! to the `wrapper` class, you can test that by increasing `height` of the area like `300px`

Comment: @Awais https://jsfiddle.net/ngoctuan001/cgLvh62o/5/ <= i tried, it not works. I think its only works if "wrapper" is div, not textarea

Comment: @NgocTuanLam I think it can't be done because space is also consider a character. Based on the total characters only text-align will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately there is no concrete CSS solution at the time of writing
>   to achieve the desired result

**Alternative: use `contenteditable`**

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #eee;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text" contenteditable=true>click here and edit</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that there is no way to do this with textarea, however div or p works fine. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

put your text in p tag and you can try

```
.wrapper
{
display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the contentEditable="true" on a div.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

```
<div class="wrapper" contentEditable="true">
  THE GREAT BANGKOK SALE
</div>
```

This will make the content correctly center and also you can edit it.

To get the content you:

```
const content = document.querySelector('.wrapper').innerText;
```